# How to call PullRequestQuery Azure Git API?

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am having hard time in calling PullRequestQuery API, Can someone help.
My goal is to get the PR associated with a commit hash.
For that I am using below API.

[PullRequestQuery API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequestquery?api-version=6.0
```

With Body:

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "type": "commit",
            "items": [
                "d59420dc1d42d54ba89ddc8731800244c351f75b",
                "e093410f49dded0c6e9703a61aca0fa0f668a78e",
                "8e3eb7f090a75cc36c9d6e649993dcd0ac6bd232",
                "c9eda1e777aec0226185b766f8d680489f2f6119",
                "73d2986aba3c9e4c44ee265765299f1dfec20c95"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "results": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

Whenever I call this API with above body, I am getting the response same as body. And, it's showing status as "201 created".

Answer (score 2):

> How to call PullRequestQuery Azure Git API?

To use this REST API, we need to pay attention to the following **three points**:

1. The commit IDs in the request body need comes from **completed** PR. In other words, we could only use this REST API to query the **completed** PRs associated with a commit hash.
2. This REST API **not** work when you select the merge type **Squash merge**, please try to select the option `Merge (no fast forward)`.
3. The commit items could not **only** contain merge commits.

   For example, there are three commits for the PR, the latest one `e9bff8e1` is the merge commit:

[image]

My test result (With commit id 2 in above image `3d0cfa96`):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into my query and passing valuable inputs, Leo. I have posted the answer for this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Information passed by "Leo Liu" is very useful. But, the problem is in the body during API call. if I take type as lastMergeCommit instead of commit, it worked.

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "type": "lastMergeCommit",
            "items": [
                "d59420dc1d42d54ba89ddc8731800244c351f75b",
                "e093410f49dded0c6e9703a61aca0fa0f668a78e",
                "8e3eb7f090a75cc36c9d6e649993dcd0ac6bd232",
                "c9eda1e777aec0226185b766f8d680489f2f6119",
                "73d2986aba3c9e4c44ee265765299f1dfec20c95"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "results": [
        {}
    ]
}
```